# regex: multiline with separation line pattern

Tags: java, regex, multiline

I have this monster of a file. It can be split in blocks that look like this:

```
========
Title: title 1
optional subtitle
====
content 1
content 2

content 3

====
Title: title 2
========
content 4
content 5
content 6
```

So, we have two blocks there, right?

I'm trying to split with something like this:

```
(?:^=+\n)(^Title: .*\n)(^.*\n)?(?:^=+\n)((.*\n)(?!=+))+
```

Now, I can See that the groups get separated fine, I get the two groups (this is in Java, by the way, using `Pattern.compile` using `Pattern.MULTILINE`) but when I want to get the **content**, that part is empty. It is being included as part of the whole group (if I call match.group() with no index, but group(3) or group(4) fail to capture anything). What am I missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works `(?:^=+\n)(^Title: .*\n)(^.*\n)?(?:^=+\n)(((.*\n)(?!=+))+)`. You should group the last part.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option:

```
String input = "========\nTitle: title 1\noptional subtitle\n====\ncontent 1\ncontent 2\n\ncontent 3\n\n====\nTitle: title 2\n========\ncontent 4\ncontent 5\ncontent 6";
String[] parts = input.split("(?s)=+\nTitle:.*?\n=+");
for (int i=1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("PART " + i + ":");
    System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```

This prints:

```
PART 1:

content 1
content 2

content 3


PART 2:

content 4
content 5
content 6
```

Note carefully that I use the `(?s)` flag when doing the regex split, to make sure that dot can match across newlines (i.e. I use DOT ALL mode).  Also, I ignore the first empty element in the array, which arose because the file started with a delimiter.  That is, we only want elements 2 onward in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

To get `title`, `subtitle`, *and* `content`, and to not have to repeat too much in the regex (simpler and better performance), I'd do it by matching the header, and manually capturing the content.

The content is allowed to contain any text that doesn't match a full header.

```
public class Section {
    private final String title;
    private final String subtitle;
    private String content;

    public Section(String title, String subtitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;

    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public String getSubtitle() {
        return this.subtitle;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public static List<Section> parse(String fileContent) {
        List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();
        Section section = null;
        int start = 0;
        final String regex = "(?m)^=+\\RTitle: (.*)\\R(?:(?!=)(.*)\\R)?=+\\R";
        for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(fileContent); m.find(); ) {
            if (section != null)
                section.setContent(fileContent.substring(start, m.start()).stripTrailing());
            section = new Section(m.group(1), m.group(2));
            sections.add(section);
            start = m.end();
        }
        if (section != null)
            section.setContent(fileContent.substring(start).stripTrailing());
        return sections;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
String fileContent = Files.readString(Paths.get("Test.txt"));
List<Section> sections = Section.parse(fileContent);
for (Section section : sections) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + section.getTitle());
    if (section.getSubtitle() != null)
        System.out.println("Subtitle: " + section.getSubtitle());
    System.out.println(section.getContent());
    System.out.println("------");
}
```

*Output*

```
Title: title 1
Subtitle: optional subtitle
content 1
content 2

content 3
------
Title: title 2
content 4
content 5
content 6
------
```